# How to set raise_on_missing_translations for I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

In `rails 6.1.6.1` I have the following deprecation warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: action_view.raise_on_missing_translations is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.0. Set i18n.raise_on_missing_translations instead. Note that this new setting also affects how missing translations are handled in controllers.
```

How do I set the `raise_on_missing_translations` option, and where do I set it (e.g. in an initializer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set config [like this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2953ae5c8a06f2d794350f1e1278253531b65d2e/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/environments/development.rb.tt#L72-L73) in `application.rb` or in specific environments:

```rb
config.i18n.raise_on_missing_translations = true
```